# Unexpected token ILLEGAL error when updating Mongo document

Tags: mongodb

I'm new at mongo and I know this is a really silly question but I've been at it for awhile but can not get my document to update.
Below is what I have:

```
db.Users.update({"_id": 55b6fd7f2308d1c54c33cf44},
{ $set: {
  DateCreated : {Year : {$year: "$date"},
                 Month : {$month: "$date"},
                 Day : {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},
                 }
         }

})
```

I followed the example provided in the mongo site.

```
db.books.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $inc: { stock: 5 },
     $set: {
       item: "ABC123",
       "info.publisher": "2222",
       tags: [ "software" ],
       "ratings.1": { by: "xyz", rating: 3 }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: Those are [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). They are for use with the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method and not the `.update()` method. What are you trying to do here? Set a date? Or set new fields based on the date already in your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you meant:

```
db.Users.update({"_id": ObjectId("55b6fd7f2308d1c54c33cf44")},
{ $set: { DateCreated : new Date()  } })
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the response I was looking at date types and thought I would add it to my users type but I missed the part about using .aggregate as mentioned by Blakes.